# Search Filters Results Unexpectedly

Tags: query, plugin-supertable

This question is related to: [SuperTable Returning Unexpected Results w/ Template](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/36690/supertable-returning-unexpected-results-w-template), which is still unresolved.

In essence, Im trying to return the results of a Supertable at two different points in my template.

```
{% set featuredContributorsGrouped = entry.contributors
    .search('terms')
    .all()
    |group('contribution[0]')
%}
```

Appears in my template first, but when I try and reuse entry.contributors.all, it seems like it is already filtered by `terms`. This happens even if I recast `entry` as another temporary variable.

I was able to get around this by saving the full results as its own temporary variable *before* filtering it, but perhaps I'm not understanding how Craft queries modify entry information. I would assume it would be non destructive?

Answer (score 1):

This is a change in behaviour from Craft 2 to Craft 3 and [here is the explanation](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/upgrade.html#cloning-element-queries).

In short, you need to `clone` your query ([docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/dev/functions.html#clone)) - [see this post](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/37476/3630) for more info.

Comment: Thank you!! 